# m4 macro processing, foreach loop with multiple arguments

Tags: bash, unix, macros, m4

I am currently making a rudimentary m4 macro script to do some expanding of text blocks.

However I am currently stuck at this:

```
divert(-1)
# foreach(x, (item_1, item_2, ..., item_n), stmt)
define(`foreach', `pushdef(`$1', `')_foreach(`$1', `$2', `$3')popdef(`$1')')
define(`_arg1', `$1')
define(`_foreach',
    `ifelse(`$2', `()', ,
        `define(`$1', _arg1$2)$3`'_foreach(`$1', (shift$2), `$3')')')
divert

define(`ablock',`ROLE=$1 CUSTOMER= $2')dnl


foreach(`i', ((`GUY', `TEST'), (`FOO', `BAR')) , ablock(`i'))
```

The output of this is:

```
ROLE=(GUY,TEST) 
CUSTOMER= 
ROLE=(FOO,BAR) 
CUSTOMER=
```

When the expected output would be:

```
ROLE=GUY 
CUSTOMER=TEST
```

So the `i` is not equal to two arguments then? How would one go about doing that in that case as I'd probably want even more arguments to feed into 'ablock' at some point. If there are any pointers on how to do this it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why redefined foreach ? Is it just to retain the value of the iteration variable (`i`) ?